# Error al recorrer las filas de una tabla en C#

Tags: c#

Ya tengo la estructura basica o sintactica que deberia hacer funcionar a mi bucle, pero por alguna razon me sale este error:

> Error 20  La instrucción foreach no puede funcionar en variables de
>   tipo 'System.Data.DataTable' porque 'System.Data.DataTable' no
>   contiene ninguna definición pública para
>   'GetEnumerator'   C:\Users\NQ054\Desktop\SGSIA\App_Code\configuracion\Empresa.cs  141 8   C:...\SGSIA\

La sintaxis de mi foreach es la siguiente

```
   foreach (DataRow datos in plantas)
   {
       crearHTML(datos.ToString);
   }
```

La creacion de mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
    storedProcedure sp = new storedProcedure("DBSGSIAConnectionString");
   DataTable plantas;
   plantas = new DataTable();
   string planta;
    string query = "select * from v_DatosEmpresa;";
    plantas = sp.getValues(query);
   planta= Convert.ToString(plantas);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambia esta linea:

```
foreach (DataRow datos in plantas)
```

por esta otra:

```
foreach (DataRow datos in plantas.rows)
```

De esta forma también puede funcionar:

```
foreach (var datos in plantas.rows)
```

**Explicación:**

No puedes iterar el objeto `DataTable`, pero si puedes iterar o recorrer la colección de `rows` que contiene, de allí deriva el error.

Saludos.

Comment: Bastante concreta y muy buena respuesta :)

Comment: Muchas gracias :-)